# OpenGL rendering crash during Flutter app startup on IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, crash

I have an app developed in Flutter, I track its crashes by Firebase Crashlytics.

According to it in 99% of the time it is crash free, but during 1% of the sessions on IOS I have a strange crash at startup of the app.

```
OpenGL rendering while app in background state
keyboard_arrow_up

Crashed: io.flutter.1.gpu
0  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib     0x2374b2fe4 gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient + 12
1  AGXGLDriver                    0x23b9fcec8 gldUpdateDispatch + 7184
2  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib     0x2374b3fac gpusSubmitDataBuffers + 176
3  AGXGLDriver                    0x23b9fe3f4 gldUpdateDispatch + 12604
4  GLEngine                       0x23cb95234 gliPresentViewES_Exec + 184
5  OpenGLES                       0x21e8ddaa4 -[EAGLContext presentRenderbuffer:] + 80
6  Flutter                        0x100a54e84 (Missing)
7  Flutter                        0x100da8e18 (Missing)
8  Flutter                        0x100aad2d8 (Missing)
9  Flutter                        0x100a9dcf0 (Missing)
10 Flutter                        0x100a9e15c (Missing)
11 Flutter                        0x100a9e868 (Missing)
12 Flutter                        0x100a9dfe4 (Missing)
13 Flutter                        0x100aa2d94 (Missing)
14 Flutter                        0x100a63098 (Missing)
15 Flutter                        0x100a6448c (Missing)
16 CoreFoundation                 0x21b66a8f4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
17 CoreFoundation                 0x21b66a624 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 864
18 CoreFoundation                 0x21b669e58 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 248
19 CoreFoundation                 0x21b664da8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1844
20 CoreFoundation                 0x21b664354 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
21 Flutter                        0x100a64318 (Missing)
22 Flutter                        0x100a63be8 (Missing)
23 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x21b2f82c0 _pthread_body + 128
24 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x21b2f8220 _pthread_start + 44
25 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x21b2fbcdc thread_start + 4
```

Do you have similar experiences? Is there any way to fix it?

Thanks a lot!